# How to opt out from Open Graph Beta?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I've updated my Facebook application to use Open Graph by mistake, and now I have the new auth dialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/).

How can I return to the old auto dialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to cancel your selection of the `Enhanced Auth Dialog` setting in the advanced tab of your application settings.

[image]